# Conditional HTML (depending on yaml front matter)

Tags: html, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I am a self confessed webtard so go easy. Using Jekyll I have a site where the content is pumped through a liquid filter to generate a table of contents. The default.html file contains a little something like this . . .

```
<div id='content'>
    {{ content | toc }}
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

How can I use the yaml front matter (with something like `do_toc: true`) to make the table of contents appear only on specified pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to define a different layout for those pages that need the table of contents and those that don't.  It sounds like you are using `default.html` as the template for all your content.  Instead, make a copy of `default.html` called something else, e.g. `toc.html`, and then edit that file (erg, that does mean you'll have to edit in HTML) to have the `div` block you provide where you want it.

Then in pages that need toc, in the yaml header, just use

```
--- 
layout: toc.html
---
```

instead of

```
--- 
layout: default.html
---
```

Note: There's no need to copy `default.html`.  Simply add create a file named `toc.html` to your `_layouts` directory with the following contents:

```
---
layout: default.html
---
<div id='content'>
 {{ content | toc }}
 {{ content }}
</div>
```

and then write your yaml headers for your pages as shown.  No duplication of HTML at all.

Comment: That is one way to do it but it means a lot of HTML code duplication. It is not very DRY.

Comment: I don't follow.  It doesn't involve any HTML duplication.  You have two different kinds of layouts: pages with TOCs and pages without, so you specify two different layouts.  I've modified my answer to show a slightly more elegant way to do specify your second layout.

Comment: Ooops +1. I did say I was a webtard. My bad

Comment: Ooops +1/Accept. I did say I was a webtard.... thanks for the simplification. My bad. I thought I'd have to copy/paste the whole file with 1 tiny modification.

Comment: Oh, and congrats on breaking 1K :)